# Why can't I block until I am attacked?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Every time I enter a fight, my guy will not block no matter how many times I right click. He gets attacked as a result. I use my hidden blade most of the time.

This is really frustrating on some missions where 100% sync requires that you do not take any damage.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target an enemy before you can block even if you have a weapon drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the PC version is anything like the console versions, blocking isn't a toggle action. You hold down the button (or click-hold your mouse) to activate blocking. While your button (or mouse click) is held, you will block every incoming attack.

Comment: I know, I am holding it down, but he does take a blocking stance!

Comment: @drozzy So that means it's working?

Comment: No, it's not! I meant that I tried doing all kinds of things: hold it down, click it repeatedly, left-click temporarily (which works with a sword - because he pulls it out, but not with a hidden-blade because he just reverts back to "non-fighting" position, and block doesn't do anything).

Comment: Since this is your first move, you'll probably have target an enemy to get into "fighting stance".

Comment: When you say you're mainly using the hidden blade, do you mean you don't draw your sword at the beginning of a battle? This might be the problem because you can't block attacks with your hidden blade.

Comment: fighting stance is required for blocking. you can block attacks even with bare hands, Ezio uses the forearm (the one protected by the hidden blade). you just need to be in fighting stance, or you will faill 100% of the time the first block. also, you need to keep the block button pressed